# Python 3 Use case for continue instead of not (!=)

Tags: python, loops, continue

So I'm learning Python finally and I've just learned about skipping to the next iteration of a loop using continue. Now my question is, what would be a real world use case for continue instead of not or != ?

Consider the three pieces of simple code below:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    if i == 3:
        continue
    print(i)

for i in range(0, 10):
    if i != 3:
        print(i)

for i in range(0, 10):
    if i == 3:
        log()
    print(i)
```

In my mind, I don't see why I should prefer the first to the second. I found another question regarding continue, and someone mentioned about using it when they wanted to log something, but in that case, why not use the third example?

I fully understand that for such a simple example as I've given, the difference probably isn't much but could someone tell me when I should prefer continue? Or is it just more of a "avoiding the use of !=" case?

Comment: if you're in a very deep "if" test continue allows to skip the rest. You cannot do that with just inverting the condition

Comment: Sometimes you want to continue on an exception and not a condition, it's useful to use `continue` in the `except` block

Comment: Isn’t this off-topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`continue` for a loop is just like `return` to a function: a convenience instruction to skip to the next iteration *right now*.

On a complex case, `continue` can skip to the next iteration very simply:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    if i != 3:
        print("something")
        if my_function(i) != 34:
           continue
    print(i)
```

To do that without `continue`, you need a flag or `else` conditions. Careful as if there are a lot of `continue` statements in your loops it can become difficult to debug (just like when you put too many `return` statements in a function)